# Add fields to laravel form dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel

I have a Laravel form that collects info from a user.  On one part of the form I want to add a button that will add a row containing 4 text boxes (each named differently) that the user can fill in.  Each time the user clicks the button, another row of 4 text boxes should be added.

In an ideal world, the code will be a javascript function (so I can reuse it later) called by a button click.  I can't seem to see how to add an event handler to a button click on a laravel form.

Comment: please show your code it will be useful to recognize your question more easily

Answer (score 3):

This works
**HTML**

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $("#rm").remove(); 

            $(wrapper).append('<div id="divs"><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/>'); //add input box
             $(wrapper).append('<div id="divs"><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/>'); //add input box
              $(wrapper).append('<div id="divs"><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/></div>'); //add input box
               $(wrapper).append('<div id="divs"><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" id="rm" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
                $(wrapper).append('<br>')
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $("#divs").remove(); x--;
        $("#divs").remove(); x--;
        $("#divs").remove(); x--;
        $("#divs").remove(); x--;

    })
});
```

the name will be  mytext (first input name = `mytest[1]`    second `mytest[2]`  ...etc)
you can add the X variable to the form so you know how many input you have in your controller

in the html , you can change the type to hidden so you want have any input fields untill user click

**check result this i**n [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdgoc0rr/1/)